# typescript generate possible function argument combination from interface/ object like type

Tags: typescript, typing

I am having a TypeScript type (that i could implement as an interface as well) that defines all possible handler names for a queue message as well as the data type the handler does expect.

```
export type JobDataTypes = {
    'user-handler': {
        firstname: string;
    };
    'calendar-handler': {
        memberId: number;
        appointmentId: number;
    };
};
```

I now want to create a function `insertToQueue(jobType: keyof JobDataTypes, data) => void` that accepts based on the given `jobType` only the correct data type from the `JobDataTypes` type above. As i need the data types on multiple places, I do not want to hardcode it with overwriting the function type. how would I have to implement a `type InsertToQueueParams` type in order to accomplish that goal?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a simple use-case for generics.

```
function insertToQueue<
  K extends keyof JobDataTypes
>(jobType: K, data: JobDataTypes[K]){}
```

We can use the generic type `K` to represent the `keyof JobDataTypes` passed with `jobType`. The `data` paremeter can now be typed with `JobDataTypes[K]`.

```
insertToQueue("user-handler", { firstname: "" })
insertToQueue("calendar-handler", { memberId: 0, appointmentId: 0 })
insertToQueue("calendar-handler", { firstname: "" }) // Error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=62&pln=15&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBSEBGARAhjXAFWWAGc4BeOAbwCg4G4ByAV1OCgFoALXAOwAmAGw5MAXDXqNpAMwCWUUjD64AtsAlKocvgHMA3FIYBfQ9KYBjXCMG4uvQSKjjJ06etWYOASQES+LJ4cZm4MuGCQOjDqfDC+-oFeUCEmhqa0tDIsfBYwchB8cDrssIQQAIoswFUAPFIA0nCgMMCC5ADWwIgQMuhYeATEKKS0AHwAFABWWEMacPUANHAC+LgSGDirs6QA2vUAugCU1MYZxRwwZZXVwOMARGwcPPzCHHdL1HDyispqc3d3ODGQ60c6lCpVKr3Kw2Fb2F5Od40OAeJLxOAABiW4UisRicT8mKBILBlwhN2h1lacOejjeHy+CiUKnUEgBxLgAHpOXAAKJQKDQIA)